# Add editable dynamic objects to an array in Mithriljs

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I have an array, that I need to populate with multiple `'properties'`, something like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Date',
        value: '27 Oct'
    },
    {
        name: 'Type',
        value: 'Image'
    },
    {
        name: 'Client',
        value: 'Apple'
    }
]
```

I want to list out all the `properties` in `ul` and I want to have a `+` button, that will add a new object to an array (initially `name` and `value` will be blank). After double clicking on each item (`li` in this case), I want to make these `properties` editable.

So I did something like this:

```
var Properties = {};

Properties.items = [
    {
        name: m.prop('Date'),
        value: m.prop('21 Dec'),
        editable: m.prop(false)
    }
];
```

This is my initial array.

Then, I have a controller:

```
Properties.controller = function() {
    this.addNewItem = function() {
        Properties.items.push({
            name: m.prop('Sample'),
            value: m.prop('Test'),
            editable: m.prop(false)
        })
    };

    this.toggleEditable = function(item) {
        item.editable(!item.editable());
        console.log(item.editable());
    };
};
```

My view:

```
Properties.view = function(ctrl) {
    return m('ul.list-unstyled', [
        Properties.items.map(function(item) {
            return m('li', [
                item.editable() ? m('input', {
                    value: item.name(),
                    onkeyup: function(e) {
                        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                            ctrl.toggleEditable.bind(ctrl, item);
                        } else {
                            m.withAttr('value', item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }) :
                m('span', {
                    ondblclick: ctrl.toggleEditable.bind(ctrl, item)
                }, item.name()),
                m('span', ': '),
                m('span', item.value())
            ]);
        }),
        m('div',{
            onclick: ctrl.addNewItem.bind(ctrl)
        }, '+')
    ]);
};
```

And finally:

```
m.mount(document.querySelector('.container'), Properties);
```

But when I start typing, it sort of overwrites what I wrote and doesn't save the new value..

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You should keep your original array as the data model, pass it to `Properties` and let `Properties` store only the editable state. That is a nice data separation and will simplify the code. It may fix the save problem as well, since it can just set the array value directly in the `onkeyup` event.

For the overwrite problem, maybe adding a `key` attribute will work? It seems related. Check out http://mithril.js.org/mithril.html#dealing-with-focus for more information.